# how can I use winjs 4.4.0 in the web site as jQueryUI or other UI framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, winjs

I not have use `jQuery`, `extjs`, other `UI` except `WinJS` (`mb` with angular-winjs).
I mean, I need instructions on how I can use winjs not in the application (such as windows store app), but in a regular cross-platform site using winjs

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but I think you are looking for a winjs CDN https://cdnjs.com/libraries/winjs - Add as necessary.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/winjs/4.4.0/css/ui-dark.min.css"></script>
```

Comment: nop, read in the title. And I change mi question in description for many text